# How to set correct path in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, codeigniter-2

I have an application with domen for example: blog.myblog.com and inside I have a folder call content when I want to upload images.  How to correct set this lines img_path and the upload_path:

```
$config['img_path'] = '/myblog.com/content'; // Relative to domain name
$config['upload_path'] = '/var/www/blog'. $config['img_path']; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]
```

I use nginx as server..

Comment: I use them relative to my root index.php, if set full path, always use physical.

Answer (score 0):

well i have don the image upload stuff i think codeigniter generate ur base_url automatically so you can just have something like this `$dir = './content';
                    $config['upload_path'] = $dir;` try that but don't know if the server type will affect it.

Answer (score 0):

You can better add a baseurl in the config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

and then use it like :

```
$config['upload_path'] = .base_url().'/path/to/your/file'. $config['img_path'];
```

Hope this would help